# MarkLogic integration with Dropwizard

Tags: marklogic, dropwizard, marklogic-8

I am trying to use MarkLogic DB in Dropwizard application for data persistence. I tried with different versions combinations but still facing issues.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DurationSerializer.(DurationSerializer.java:28)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DurationSerializer.(DurationSerializer.java:25)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule.(JodaModule.java:45)
>     at io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson.configure(Jackson.java:56)     at
>   io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson.newObjectMapper(Jackson.java:23)    at
>   io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.(Bootstrap.java:64)   at
>   io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)

Snapshot of dependencies:

io.dropwizard dropwizard-core 0.9.3 io.federecio dropwizard-swagger 0.7.0 com.marklogic java-client-api 3.0.5

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do a dependency tree and see what versions of databind you have in your dependencies. Also either try excluding DW from the swagger dependency, or use the right version of dropwizard in the first place (I believe 0.7.x)